# How can I select columns and values like rows?

Tags: mysql, pivot

I want to select more columns,and I want to use it in PHP for(), but I want to work with rows.

```
 SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I FROM test;
 result:
 A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
 1   2   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
```

But I want:

```
 A 1
 B 2
 C 3
 D 4  
 ...
 I 10
```

Comment: Show sample output for when there are multiple rows in test?

Comment: If you are doing this this with only one row of data, then it would be simpler to traverse the columns in PHP after returning that row as an array. If you need this with multiple rows that become multiple columns, then it *must* be done in PHP with a pair of arrays. Otherwise you’re wasting a lot of processing power for little gain …

Comment: One possible way I can think of is using `UNION ALL`.. but that will definitely form a long query.. What if your columns doesn't end at `I` and instead it's beyond `Z`? For example you have `A1` after `Z` until `Z99`? Maybe it's time to re-think the table design.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but thought this could help if you didn't already know about it.
Using \G instead of semi-colon (;) to execute a statement will cause the output to be in vertical format. Example:
SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I FROM test\G
result:
*************************** 1. row ***************************
A 1
*************************** 2. row ***************************
A 2
etc....

Comment: This kind of problem is rather indicative of poor schema design